# Nested Array of object need to convert to array object with async/await with two loop

Tags: javascript, json, async-await, promise, es6-promise

Might be question is look like duplicate but mine case is different. since I have implemented solution for same but it is working **Synchronous loop** but I want to implement **Asynchronous  loop**. I am unable to implement it.

**Synchronous loop Solution :**

Input data is coming from API.

```js
let input = [  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "domain":"bank",
      "projects":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"home loan",
            "amount":["123","345","45"]
         },
         {  
            "id":2,
            "name":"car load",
            "amount":["123","34","45"]
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id": 2,
      "domain":"game",
      "projects":[  
         {  
            "id":3,
            "name":"cricket",
            "amount":["13","4","45"]
         },
         {  
            "id":4,
            "name":"Kabadi",
            "amount":["3","4","5"]
         }
      ]
   }
];





const transformation = data => {
  let counter = 0;
  let domainProjects = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    let len = data[index].projects;
    for (let j = 0; j < len.length; j++) {
      domainProjects[counter] = {
        domain: data[index].domain,
        project: len[j].name,
        amount: len[j].amount,
      };
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return domainProjects;
};
const result = transformation(input);
console.log("Result:",result);
```

**Asynchronous  loop**
expected result :

```
  expectResult =[
    {
        "domain":"bank",
        "name":"home loan",
        "amount":["123","345","45"]
    },
    {
        "domain":"bank",
        "name":"car load",
        "amount":["123","34","45"]
    },
    {
        "domain":"game",
        "name":"cricket",
        "amount":["13","4","45"]
    },
    {
        "domain":"game",
        "name":"Kabadi",
        "amount":["3","4","5"]
    }
];
```

Comment: What have you currently tried towards making the asynchronous loop?

Comment: I am unable to understand . how to implement and start

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? Where is the source of your data? Why do you think you need an async loop?

Comment: why do you need async loop?

Comment: In your code the needed data has already been fetched so what is asynchronous?

Comment: If you want to make it asynchronous, you can just make a `new Promise()`.  Have that run your code, then `resolve()` it with the result (`domainProjects`).

Comment: Input data is coming from API. and before passing data to action reducer need to transform the data . you can see input json format and expected result.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Sir if possible then could you please post answer . it will be great help

Comment: @PramodKharade How are you getting the data from the API?  it sounds like you just need to move your `transformation` function into the callback from that.  What are you trying to do with the "transformed" data?  What is "action reducer?"  We need more info on what problem you are trying to solve.  Can you show us what the problem here is?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Sir, basically, Above use case, I am implement  in reactjs with redux

Comment: @PramodKharade I've never uses reactjs (and I don't know what redux is).  What are you doing with the `result`?  Or rather, what are you trying to do with `result`?  What is wrong with your code?  Does it not work?  What is the *actual* code you have that you are trying to fix?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Sir Could you please help with same example to convert to Asynchronous operation? Above code is working but it is working as synchronous but I would like to convert to Asynchronous

Comment: @PramodKharade If nothing asynchronous is happening in your code, you cannot make it asynchronous. You don't seem to have a goal with asynchrony, no problem to solve, just keep it synchronous!

Answer (score -1):

This is untested and not guaranteed to work, but it is definitely the general basis and you should be able to get it from here. In order to go through a loop asynchronously, it has to contain async and await statements.

```
const transformation = async () => {
    let counter = 0;
    let domainProjects = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
            let len = data[index].projects;
            for (let j = 0; j < len.length; j++) {
                domainProjects[counter] = {
                domain: data[index].domain,
                project: len[j].name,
                amount: len[j].amount,
            };
            counter++;
        }
        resolve(domainProjects);
    });
}

const result = transformation(input).then((v) => console.log(v));
```

Comment: Do you actually `async` here?  The function is returning a `Promise` and you're not using `await`, so I don't think it's needed.  Also, you don't define `data` anywhere.  `data` needs to be a parameter to the `transformation` function.

Comment: Also, note that `result` is going to be a `Promise` and not the output array (`domainProjects`).